# Decomposition of 2 fourth order differential equations on 4 equations of second order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to make decomposition of 2 fourth order differential equations on 4 equations of second order

$$C_1x''''+C_2x'''+C_3x''+C_4x'+C_5x-C_6y''-C_7y=0$$

$$D_1y''''+D_2y'''+D_3y''+D_4y'+D_5y-D_6x''-D_7x=0$$

Known constants $$C_i,  D_i$$

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

Define $w=x''$ and $v=y''$.

Comment: Substitution is ok, but I need 4 equations of second order because I must got the system which is the same with some which I already have. To see which influence have the different constants on some parts of equations. I must got system like this one:

q1''+A1*q1'+A2*q1-A3*q2=0
q2''+B1*q2'+B2*q2-B3*q1=0

I know that my system can not reduce on this one, but I can maybe ignore some of high derivative of functions?

Comment: @Derdack: maybe I don't understand you completely: you get 4 equations. 2 are given as a hint. The other two are in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Write your system in the matrix form
$\bf{z}^{\prime}=A\mathbf{z},$
where $\bf{z}=\left(  x,x^{\prime},x^{\prime\prime},x^{\prime\prime\prime
},y,y^{\prime},y^{\prime\prime},y^{\prime\prime\prime}\right)  ^{T}$ (you can divide the first equation with $C_{1}$ and the second one with $D_{1}%
$, assuming these are non-zero). Now try
to find a transformation $\bf{z=}T\mathbf{q}$
such that $\bf{q}^{\prime}=T^{-1}AT\mathbf{q}$ has the required form (here $\mathbf{q}=\left(  q_{1},q_{1}^{\prime},q_{2},q_{2}^{\prime},q_{3},q_{3}^{\prime},q_{4},q_{4}^{\prime}\right)  ^{T}$ with your notation). Is this possible?